# Odd behaviour with XmlReader.Read and Stream.Read

Tags: c#, xml, iostream

I've encountering an unusual problem with .Net Framework 3.5 and the System.Xml.XmlReader class.

Before my application calls the XmlReader.Read method it first reads the content of the stream for logging purposes using the Stream.Read method.  It then seeks back to the beginning of the stream before calling Stream.Read.  When I do this I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line 1, position 4097.
```

If however I call XmlReader.Read, seek to the beginning of the stream and then call the Stream.Read method it all works fine.  This only appears to be happening on large streams however.  I've just seen one go through the system at about 2000 characters and it works fine?

I've included a code sample below to give an idea of what I'm doing.

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.Schemas.Add(null, args[1]);
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
readerSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(XmlValidatingReaderValidationEventHandler);

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileReader, readerSettings);

byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
string content = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

while(reader.Read());

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `XmlReader` buffers the data from the `Stream`. If you mess with the current position of the `Stream`, you mess with the `XmlReader` too...

Comment: Thanks, its odd though that simply reading a stream and then returning to the start would mess it up like this. I've done another using a memory stream with the same result. I've done something similar in C++ before which worked fine?

Answer (score 1):

Messing around with the stream which is backing something like `XmlReader` is generally a bad idea. If you want to do two different things with the same file, I suggest you open two different streams. That way they won´t interfere with each other.

Note that using [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) is a simpler way of loading the contents of a text file into a string.

Comment: It is indeed, the actual app however isn't working with files so I just copied over what it was doing. If I was randomly locating it's pointer I'd expect this behaviour but as I'm returning to the start and its only with large streams it just strokes me as odd

Comment: @daz-fuller: You're returning it to the start, but you don't know what it's already done. It may have read a byte-order mark to detect the encoding, for example. Then you're putting it back to the start, and the BOM is there again, which would confuse it...

Comment: @jon-skeet checked it through and it appears that when calling the XmlReader.Create method it reads the first 4096 characters of the stream or to the end of the stream.  Of course if there is more to be read then reading the stream from elsewhere will cause it to lose it's position.  It is possible to do what I was trying to above by recording the streams position and then return the stream to the same position after performing the second read.

Comment: @daz-fuller: Yes, that should work - but I would still try to avoid touching it at all, if you possibly can.